# Split and group array by keys

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

Alright, I've done some searching and haven't found an answer, so I'm going to give this a shot.

I have a JSON file that can spit out the following info:

```
[
    {
        "Contact name(s)": "Person 1, Person 2",
        "Contact title(s)": "Head Comacho, Other Guy",
        "Contact email(s)": "email1@email.net, email@email.com",
        "Contact phone": "123-456-7890, 789-456-1230",
    },
    {   
        "Contact name(s)": "Some Dude",
        "Contact title(s)": "Cool Title",
        "Contact email(s)": "things@email.com",
        "Contact phone": "555-555-5555",
    },
        "Contact name(s)": "",
        "Contact title(s)": "",
        "Contact email(s)": "",
        "Contact phone": "",
    }
]
```

Unfortunately that is how the data is named when it comes over. Out of my hands. At any rate, I have to get it so these that have multiple contacts will group into their own arrays. Here is what It will need to look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contact_name] => Person 1
            [contact_title] => Head Comacho
            [contact_email] => email1@email.net
            [contact_phone] => 123-456-7890
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contact_name] => Person 2
            [contact_title] => Other Title
            [contact_email] => email@email.com
            [contact_phone] => 789-456-1230
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contact_name] => Some Dude
            [contact_title] => Cool Title
            [contact_email] => things@email.com
            [contact_phone] => 555-555-5555
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contact_name] => 
            [contact_title] => 
            [contact_email] => 
            [contact_phone] => 
        )
)
```

I was able to convert the data into their own arrays, looking like this:

```
Array
(
    [contact_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Person 1
            [1] => Person 2
        )

    [contact_title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Head Comacho
            [1] => Other Guy
        )

    [contact_email] => Array
        (
            [0] => email1@email.net
            [1] => email@email.com
        )

    [contact_phone] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123-456-7890
            [1] => 789-456-1230
        )

)

Array
(
 .....etc
)
```

How would I go about getting it like the first example?

Apologies if this has been answered before, I was unsure how to word my question. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you missing some fields? As it is right now, the JSON is invalid (extra comma on last field and missing opening bracket on last object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this script will do what you want. I've created a function `split_contacts` which takes each entry in the decoded array, and splits the values (e.g. `"Person 1, Person 2"` => ["Person 1", "Person 2"]) into arrays indexed by the object keys, which are massaged by the `preg_replace` into the form which you desire (e.g. `"Contact name(s)" => "contact_name"`). Note it may have been possible to use `str_replace` rather than `preg_replace`, but I wanted to keep the code flexible in terms of the format of your key values.

```
$json = '[
    {
        "Contact name(s)": "Person 1, Person 2",
        "Contact title(s)": "Head Comacho, Other Guy",
        "Contact email(s)": "email1@email.net, email@email.com",
        "Contact phone": "123-456-7890, 789-456-1230"
    },
    {   
        "Contact name(s)": "Some Dude",
        "Contact title(s)": "Cool Title",
        "Contact email(s)": "things@email.com",
        "Contact phone": "555-555-5555"
    },
    {
        "Contact name(s)": "",
        "Contact title(s)": "",
        "Contact email(s)": "",
        "Contact phone": ""
    }
]';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

function split_contact($contact) {
    $contacts = array();
    foreach ($contact as $key => $values) {
        $key = strtolower(preg_replace(array('/\(s\)$/', '/\s+/'), array('', '_'), $key));
        foreach (explode(',', $values) as $index => $value) {
            $contacts[$index][$key] = trim($value);
        }
    }
    return $contacts;
}

$newarr = array();
foreach ($arr as $contact) {
    $newarr[] = split_contact($contact);
}

print_r($newarr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [contact_name] => Person 1
                    [contact_title] => Head Comacho
                    [contact_email] => email1@email.net
                    [contact_phone] => 123-456-7890
                )    
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [contact_name] =>  Person 2
                    [contact_title] =>  Other Guy
                    [contact_email] =>  email@email.com
                    [contact_phone] =>  789-456-1230
                )    
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [contact_name] => Some Dude
                    [contact_title] => Cool Title
                    [contact_email] => things@email.com
                    [contact_phone] => 555-555-5555
                )    
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [contact_name] => 
                    [contact_title] => 
                    [contact_email] => 
                    [contact_phone] => 
                )    
        )    
)
```

Comment: Since regex is not necessary for the sample data provided, I would have rather seen the lighter call: `str_replace()`

Comment: @mickmackusa I was trying to keep the code flexible... I don't know what the rest of OPs data looks like

Comment: Please add some explanation to this code-only answer to improve its overall educational value.

Comment: @mickmackusa Your wish... oh wait, no it's not :-). But it's a fair comment and definitely this answer could use some, which I have done.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make sure that json object for multiple persons always contain exactly the same number of elements, then you can do something like that:

```
<?php

$json = '[
    {"Contact name(s)": "Person 1, Person 2", "Contact title(s)": "Head Comacho, Other Guy", "Contact email(s)": "email1@email.net, email@email.com", "Contact phone": "123-456-7890, 789-456-1230"},
    {"Contact name(s)": "Some Dude", "Contact title(s)": "Cool Title", "Contact email(s)": "things@email.com", "Contact phone": "555-555-5555"},
    {"Contact name(s)": "", "Contact title(s)": "", "Contact email(s)": "", "Contact phone": ""}
]';

$jsonA = json_decode($json, true);

$result = [];
$maxLen = 0;
foreach ($jsonA as &$obj) {
    foreach ($obj as $k => $v) {
        if (!isset($result[$k])) $result[$k] = [];
        foreach (explode(',', $v) as $av) $result[$k][] = trim($av);
        $maxLen = max($maxLen, count($result[$k]));
    }
}

$objects = [];
for ($i=0; $i<$maxLen; $i++) {
    $object = [];
    foreach (array_keys($result) as $k) $object[$k] = isset($result[$k][$i]) ? $result[$k][$i] : '';
    $objects[] = $object;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($objects);
```

it prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Contact name(s)] => Person 1
            [Contact title(s)] => Head Comacho
            [Contact email(s)] => email1@email.net
            [Contact phone] => 123-456-7890
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Contact name(s)] => Person 2
            [Contact title(s)] => Other Guy
            [Contact email(s)] => email@email.com
            [Contact phone] => 789-456-1230
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Contact name(s)] => Some Dude
            [Contact title(s)] => Cool Title
            [Contact email(s)] => things@email.com
            [Contact phone] => 555-555-5555
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Contact name(s)] => 
            [Contact title(s)] => 
            [Contact email(s)] => 
            [Contact phone] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came to this solution :

```
$arr = '[
    {
        "Contact name(s)": "Person 1, Person 2",
        "Contact title(s)": "Head Comacho, Other Guy",
        "Contact email(s)": "email1@email.net, email@email.com",
        "Contact phone": "123-456-7890, 789-456-1230"
    },
    {   
        "Contact name(s)": "Some Dude",
        "Contact title(s)": "Cool Title",
        "Contact email(s)": "things@email.com",
        "Contact phone": "555-555-5555"
    },
    {
        "Contact name(s)": "",
        "Contact title(s)": "",
        "Contact email(s)": "",
        "Contact phone": ""
    }
]';

$arr = json_decode($arr, true);

foreach ($arr as $row) {

    list($m_name, $m_title, $m_email, $m_phone) =
    [explode(',', $row["Contact name(s)"]),explode(',', $row["Contact title(s)"]),
     explode(',', $row["Contact email(s)"]),explode(',', $row["Contact phone"])];

    foreach (array_keys($m_name) as $per)
        $result[] = ['name' => $m_name[$per],'title' => $m_title[$per],
                     'email' => $m_email[$per],'phone' => $m_phone[$per]];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was my project, this is what I'd do and why...

1. You need to keep each subset of data separate from one another, so use `$temp` as temporary storage between outer loop iterations.  The temporary array must be reset at the start of each new `$set` and the temporary array data must be transferred to the `$result` array to maintain the original set indexes.
2. `explode()` is best served "comma-space" as the delimiter parameter -- this eliminates having to call any additional functions to mop up the lingering spaces.
3. Because your old and new keys are known and static, hardcoding an associative "translation" array will spare a lot of iterated function calls and largely reduce code bloat.  I will also argue that this affords you simpler control of the key preparation and future developers will quickly be able to comprehend what your code is doing.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20274a4e56c64038559f6cd7f03e9e73326954b6))

```
$json = '[
    {"Contact name(s)": "Person 1, Person 2", "Contact title(s)": "Head Comacho, Other Guy", "Contact email(s)": "email1@email.net, email@email.com", "Contact phone": "123-456-7890, 789-456-1230"},
    {"Contact name(s)": "Some Dude", "Contact title(s)": "Cool Title", "Contact email(s)": "things@email.com", "Contact phone": "555-555-5555"},
    {"Contact name(s)": "", "Contact title(s)": "", "Contact email(s)": "", "Contact phone": ""}
]';
$array = json_decode($json, true);

$trans = [
    "Contact name(s)" => "contact_name",
    "Contact title(s)" => "contact_title",
    "Contact email(s)" => "contact_email",
    "Contact phone" => "contact_phone"    
];

foreach ($array as $set) {
    $temp = [];
    foreach ($set as $key => $data) {
        foreach (explode(', ', $data) as $index => $value) {
            $temp[$index][$trans[$key]] = $value;     
        }
    }
    $result[] = $temp;
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'contact_name' => 'Person 1',
      'contact_title' => 'Head Comacho',
      'contact_email' => 'email1@email.net',
      'contact_phone' => '123-456-7890',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'contact_name' => 'Person 2',
      'contact_title' => 'Other Guy',
      'contact_email' => 'email@email.com',
      'contact_phone' => '789-456-1230',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'contact_name' => 'Some Dude',
      'contact_title' => 'Cool Title',
      'contact_email' => 'things@email.com',
      'contact_phone' => '555-555-5555',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'contact_name' => '',
      'contact_title' => '',
      'contact_email' => '',
      'contact_phone' => '',
    ),
  ),
)
```

You will find that this solution is not just concise, accurate, and easy to read; it is also very efficient because there is only one iterated function call in the whole process (`explode()`).